# Adding csp-html-webpack-plugin to vue-cli project

Tags: webpack, content-security-policy, vue-cli, html-webpack-plugin

I have a Vue2 project using vue-cli `4.5.9`. I'm trying to add the `csp-html-webpack-plugin` to `vue.config.js` so it can auto-generate hashes for JS files and insert them into the index.html file.

I looked over some documentation and have tried the following with no success:

**1.** Adding the plugin to the `configureWebpack` object:

```
configureWebpack: {
  ...
  new CspHtmlWebpackPlugin({
    'script-src': '',
    'style-src': ''
  })
}
```

**2.** Adding the plugin to the `configureWebpack` object and passing the options to the HTML plugin:

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
  config.plugin('html').tap((args) => {
    args[0].cspPlugin = {
      policy: {
          'script-src': '',
          'style-src': '',
        },
    };
    
    return args;
  });
},
...

configureWebpack: {
  ...
  new CspHtmlWebpackPlugin()
}
```

**3.** Adding the plugin and a new HTML plugin to the `configureWebpack` object:

```
configureWebpack: {
  ...
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  new CspHtmlWebpackPlugin({
    'script-src': '',
    'style-src': ''
  })
}
```

Number 3 works to output a meta tag with bounce and hash values but, the new HTML plugin overrides the vue-cli settings, which I obviously don't want to do.

Has anyone managed to add this plugin successfully to a vue-cli project before?

Is there a better way or another way of adding hashes/nonces to CSP in a vue-cli project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the exact same problem at the moment.

Comment: @felidae Sorry, I didn't manage to solve this. I think the only way to do it is option 3 but then re-add all of the options for the HtmlWebpackPlugin. I have no idea what those options are. It may also be worth asking on the Vue-cli GitHub page.

Comment: Did you solve this?? i have same issue with vue 3 composition api..